# Why is this function non-periodic?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, signal-processing

Given that $$ x(t) = \sum_{k = -5}^5 w(t - 2k) $$ where $ w(t) $ is a triangular pulse function, why would this be non-periodic?

From my understanding of the equation, $ w(t) $ will either equal $ 1 $, if $ (t - 2k) = 0 $, or $ 0 $, if $ t $ exists outside the bounds of $ -1 $ and $ 1 $.

I hand-drew the graph of $ x(t) $ between $ 0 $ and $ 10 $ and the function would show signs of repetition within the range of $ k $, hence pushing me to the idea that it IS periodic. I am not too sure how to proceed from here as the answer is non-periodic.

Additionally, the following question has a similar function: $$ x(t) = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} w(t - 3k) $$ where the answer is that it IS periodic. I do not understand the difference between the two functions.

Comment: Do you know what it means for a function to be periodic? It should be pretty clear if you just apply the definition.

Comment: @C-RAM Do you mind elaborating? I am still unsure about what you mean. The graph does repeat within the interval unless I am missing something.

Comment: The key words are "within the interval". What about outside of the interval?

Comment: @C-RAM I tried this for multiple intervals up to (-100,100) and it is periodic regardless. Does the periodicity come from the bounds of $-\infty$ to $\infty$?

Comment: Periodicity is over the entire real line (not over finite intervals). Your first function just evaluates to $0$ when $t\geq 11$. Have you tried graphing it for $t\geq 11$? You should see that it stops looking periodic (since it's just $0$) in that region. If you want to prove this formally, you need the formal definition of a periodic function, which is why I asked you if you knew the formal definition.

Comment: @C-RAM I see my problem now, I was increasing the interval of k rather than t. When applying the interval to t, the function does indeed equate to zero beyond t = 10. Thank you